# Using sentence for titles in biblatex without manually editing

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, cross-referencing, overleaf

I have a huge bib file, and I want my references to be in Sentence Case, not Title case. [I found a function that probably does it](https://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2014/10/12/Title-casing-bibtex-entry-journal-titles/), but I don't know how to use it. I am new to latex. Can anyone guide me on how to automate the process?

Edit 1: Specifically for an unformatted title in my .bib file, I want my references to be in the following format:

Capitalise every word in a title except for words like a, an, the, … unless they start the title. Do not change words with $, {} in them, or , because these are either protected or LaTeX commands.

The idea that the link I mentioned above uses is:

> The gist of our idea is to get the title, split it into words,
> capitalize each word that needs to be, join the words together, and
> then set the entry title to the new capitalized title.

Edit 2: The functions from the link I shared above:

```
defvar jmax-lower-case-words
  '("a" "an" "on" "and" "for"
    "the" "of" "in")
  "List of words to keep lowercase")

(defun jmax-title-case-article (&optional key start end)
  "Convert a bibtex entry article title to title-case. The
arguments are optional, and are only there so you can use this
function with `bibtex-map-entries' to change all the title
entries in articles."
  (interactive)
  (bibtex-beginning-of-entry)

  (let* ((title (bibtex-autokey-get-field "title"))
         (words (split-string title))
         (lower-case-words '("a" "an" "on" "and" "for"
                             "the" "of" "in")))
    (when
        (string= "article" (downcase (cdr (assoc "=type=" (bibtex-parse-entry)))))
      (setq words (mapcar
                   (lambda (word)
                     (if (or
                          ;; match words containing {} or \ which are probably
                          ;; LaTeX or protected words
                          (string-match "\\$\\|{\\|}\\|\\\\" word)
                          ;; these words should not be capitalized, unless they
                          ;; are the first word
                          (-contains? lower-case-words (s-downcase word)))
                         word
                       (s-capitalize word)))
                   words))

      ;; Check if first word should be capitalized
      (when (-contains? jmax-lower-case-words (car words))
        (setf (car words) (s-capitalize (car words))))

      ;; this is defined in doi-utils
      (bibtex-set-field
       "title"
       (mapconcat 'identity words " "))
      (bibtex-fill-entry))))
```

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please make an effort to write a question as self-contained as possible. Not only will some people be reluctant to click untrusted links, but even a good link could break in the future, making the question impossible to understand. Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Miyase Added the relevant portions from the link in the details.

Comment: @Community Have added all relevant details in edit 1 & 2.

Comment: According to the link you share, this code snippet is for Emacs. Do you use Emacs?

Comment: If you use `biblatex` to print the bibliography, there is a `\MakeSentenceCase{text}` function available. Note: the linked code is for title case, not sentence case.